# I want the side bar display first and collapse after clicking the button and adding the dropdown to the side of the menu items using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the side bar menu using `bootstrap`.

I want to hide the menu even in the large screen by clicking the button.

When collpasing to the left side menu icons should display on the left side.

Inside the menu item by clicking it dropdown to the side.

Please tell me the solution.

I tried using the `css` and `bootstrap` and `jquery`. It is not working.

```css
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 250px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: -250px;
  top: 51px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#wrapper.active {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 0;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a span:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  color: #41484c;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

#menu-toggle {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 0;
  }

  #wrapper.active {
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
  }

  #wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    left: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  }

  #menu-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
          aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify btn-menu toggle">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <nav id="spy">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav nav">
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
          <a href="#home"><span class="fa fa-home solo">Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#anch1">
            <span class="fa fa-anchor solo">Anchor 1</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#anch2">
            <span class="fa fa-anchor solo">Anchor 2</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#anch3">
            <span class="fa fa-anchor solo">Anchor 3</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#anch4">
            <span class="fa fa-anchor solo">Anchor 4</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- Page content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                Panel 1
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                content body
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-success">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                Panel 1
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                content body
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some jquery code and chaged this block of your code. rest of the code is same.

Also don't forget to add jquery, font-awesome, and bootstrap cdn in your code. (as included in the snippet below)

```
<div  class="navbar-brand">
    <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class=" btn-menu toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">Project name</a>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a#menu-toggle").click(function (){
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  padding-left: 250px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: -250px;
  top: 51px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#wrapper.active {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 0;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 70px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a span:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  color: #41484c;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

#menu-toggle {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 0;
}

#wrapper.active {
  position: relative;
  left: 250px;
}

#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
  left: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
}

}
.dropdown,.sidebar-nav,#id,#sidebar-wrapper{
  overflow:visible;
}
.dropdown>.dropdown-menu{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:100%;
  z-index:100;
  background-color:black;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:none;
  border-radius:0;
}
.dropdown>.dropdown-menu>li>a{
  line-height:45px;
  color:white;
  background-color:black;
}
.dropdown>.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
       
                <div  class="navbar-brand">
                    <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class=" btn-menu toggle">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </a>
        <a href="#">Project name</a>
                </div>
   </div>
   <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
 </nav>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <nav id="spy">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#home"><span class="fa fa-home solo">Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#anch1">
                        <span class="fa fa-anchor solo">Anchor 1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#anch2" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="fa fa-anchor solo">Anchor 2</span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                  
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#anch3">
                        <span class="fa fa-anchor solo">Anchor 3</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#anch4">
                        <span class="fa fa-anchor solo">Anchor 4</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-danger">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                    Panel 1
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                content body
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">                    
                        <div class="panel panel-success">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                    Panel 1
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                content body
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to add the drop down to the menu items

Comment: please tell me the answer

Comment: you can edit the css to alter the style and width for your dropdown-menu

Comment: no,it is not the answer i want the dropdown on the right side and menu collapsing to the left menu icons should display

Comment: okay. I updated my answer. let me know if it suits your requirement

Comment: sibe dropdown is ok but i want the icons to be displayed after collapsing the menuon the left side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131156/discussion-between-banu-prakash-and-anuja-agarwal).

Comment: sorry, banu. that is not possible with simple bootstrap. It would require some serious coding for one or two days and changes in your whole sidebar structure. Now I answered your original question you asked here, so can you please accept my answer for that. thank you

Comment: see my question

Comment: see my question and tell me the answer i will wait